# Slide a div sequentially

Tags: jquery

I have some items inside slider div and I want to animate left -299px each time click event of skip class is fired and animate back to its noramal position if it reaches its with.

Please how do I achieve this?

I tried but it only animate -299px and it stops.

I have written down some  html,css and jquery example:

**CSS**

```
<style>
.items{
    width:299px;
    height:80px;
    float:left;
    color:white;
}
.slider{
    min-width:1495px;
    height:80px;
}
.container{
    width:299px;
    height:80px;
}

.one{
background-color:red;
}
.two{
background-color:yellow;
}
.three{
background-color:red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href='#' class='skip'>Skip</a>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='slider'>
        <div class='items one'>Item 1</div>
        <div class='items two'>Item 2</div>
        <div class='items three'>Item 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
//skiping check em outerHTML

$(document).on('click','.skip',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.slider').animate({marginLeft:"-299px"},"fast");

    //stop default behaviour
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var $slider = $('.slider');
$(document).on('click','.skip',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (parseInt($slider.css('marginLeft')) < -(299 * $slider.find('.items').length - 1)) {
      $slider.animate({marginLeft:"0px"}, "fast");
    } else {
      $slider.animate({marginLeft: "-=299px"}, "fast");
    }
});
```

```css
.items{
    width:299px;
    height:80px;
    float:left;
    color:white;
}
.slider{
    min-width:1495px;
    height:80px;
}
.container{
    width:299px;
    height:80px;
}

.one{
background-color:red;
}
.two{
background-color:yellow;
}
.three{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='skip'>Skip</a>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='slider'>
        <div class='items one'>Item 1</div>
        <div class='items two'>Item 2</div>
        <div class='items three'>Item 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @james Oduro I see there was an attempt to edit this so I will follow up.  You would want to do the selector outside of the event handler so it only happens once.  This is for performance.  There is no reason to look up the element every time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is **setting** the margin-left property to become **equal** to `-299px`. If you wanted this change to work subsequently, you would have to get the previous `margin-left` value, and keep decrementing that value by how much you want.

Lucky for you, jQuery saves you the trouble of manually decrementing and supports incremental changes to CSS - just use `-=299px` instead of just `-299px`.

```js
$(document).on('click','.skip',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.slider').animate({marginLeft:"-=299px"},"fast");
    //                                ^ magic

    //stop default behaviour
    return false;
});
```

```css
.items{
    width:299px;
    height:80px;
    float:left;
    color:white;
}
.slider{
    min-width:1495px;
    height:80px;
}
.container{
    width:299px;
    height:80px;
}

.one{
background-color:red;
}
.two{
background-color:yellow;
}
.three{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='skip'>Skip</a>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='slider'>
        <div class='items one'>Item 1</div>
        <div class='items two'>Item 2</div>
        <div class='items three'>Item 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```